# An error occurred in the fscanf(), it only read the last line?

Tags: c, file, scanf

This is the code, I want to skip the last two string and read the first integer.

```
fp = fopen("test","r");
int i;
while (fscanf(fp,"%d %*s %*s",&i) > 0)
{
   printf("%d\n",i);
}
```

This is the text file:

```
4 jane good
0 may day
5 july hello
```

The program only enters the loop once and only returns the numbers in the last row.

I want to know what happened?

Comment: What do you think `fscanf(fp,"%d %*s %*s",&i)` instructs the computer to do?

Comment: It prints `4` `0` `5` for me. I think `fopen` fails on your side. Always test that `fopen` succeeds and use `perror("test");` if it fails.

Comment: Please [edit] and show the exact output you get as well as the expected output.

Comment: The asterisk in `%*s` makes it suppress that argument and skip it (read and discard) like OP wants.

Comment: @TedLyngmo if `fopen` failed, it would be a huge coincicence if his utput is `4 0 5`.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Indeed :-) He only gets `5` though.

Comment: @TedLyngmo he gets "the numbers _(plural)_ in the last row" whatever that means.

Comment: Change `int i;` to `int i = 12345;` and tell us what happens. But better [edit] and show a [mcve] including expected and actual output.

Comment: @Jabberwocky _"the numbers (plural)"_ - I assumed that plural _s_ was a mistake but given the lack of feedback we've gotten from OP, I guess anything is possible.

Comment: @Jabberwocky you seem to assume the printed `5` comes from using uninitialized variable `i`. But would `fscanf` return a positive value that is required to enter the loop body if `i` was not populated with parsed input value?

Comment: @Gerhardh I'm assuming code we don't see ....

Comment: @Gerhardh actually I don't assume anything anymore. There is simply not enough information available. But "code we don't see" probably best describes what's going on here.

Comment: Sorry everyone, I found the mistake. It turned out that I added a semicolon after the while loop, so the result was only the end of the loop. When I rewrote it, I did not add the semicolon, resulting in inconsistent code structure.

Comment: That is the reason why you are expected to show real code that produces the problem. Don't retype but copy&paste the code.

Answer (score 3):

This code generates the correct output for me:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    const char *fname = "test";
    FILE* fp = fopen(fname, "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        // custom error reporting
        fprintf(stderr, "failed to open file '%s' for reading\n", fname);
        // ... or standardised error reporting instead
        // perror(fname); 
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    int i;
    while (fscanf(fp,"%d %*s %*s",&i) > 0) {
        printf("%d\n",i);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Output:

```
4
0
5
```

I suspect you're making a mistake somewhere outside this section that you posted.

Update: I would also suggest becoming familiar with a debugger, e.g., `gdb`. I personally learned a lot of C just stepping through my programs. Also, it's very very good to check that `fopen` returns non `NULL`, as a commenter suggested. :D

Update 2: Improved error handling based on comments below. Now the file name is only hardcored in one place.

Comment: Maybe test that the file was opened successfully — to demonstrate basic good practice.

Comment: You should add an error check in your code. Not error checking `fopen` is the source of probably 20% of C questions involving opening and reading files.

Comment: Error messages should be reported on `stderr`, not `stdout`.  There's also an argument that you should only pass string variables as the file name to `fopen()`, so that you can use the file name when reporting the error message.  However, that's probably one step beyond what the OP needs.  I'd use `const char *fname = "test"; if ((fp = fopen(fname, "r")) == NULL) { fprintf(stderr, "failed to open file '%s' for reading\n", fname); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }`, or I'd add `<errno.h>` and `<string.h>` and use `errno` and `strerror()` to report the o/s error message too.

Comment: On Linux, see also the [`err(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/err.3.html)
family of functions.  I have my own variant of those — you can find that code in my [SOQ](https://github.com/jleffler/soq) (Stack Overflow Questions) repository on GitHub as files `stderr.c` and `stderr.h` in the [src/libsoq](https://github.com/jleffler/soq/tree/master/src/libsoq) sub-directory.

Comment: Thanks! I checked the code and will update the answer above.

Comment: @Surge It's better but use `perror` to see what the actual reason for the failure was and there's no need to first create the `FILE` pointer and then to assign it. Initialize it directly from `fopen`. [example](https://godbolt.org/z/hEMqfW9T8)